# How "request.security" process expression?

Tags: pine-script

From the script '*Volume-based Support & Resistance Zones V2*' in TV, there is an expression applied to a `request.security` call on line 631 (see code below)

As I understand it, the function `TF4_CalcFractalUpZone` is applied to the series of ticks requested (I don't see any access to that series inside the function as the TF4_Close[] and other variables are declared outside of the function)

`TF4_FractalUpZone` is declared as a float, so why is it accessed through index `TF4_FractalUpZone[1]` at the end of the 2nd function line?

```
// Zones - Current Time Frame = Time Frame 4 = TF4
// Fractal Up Zones
TF4_CalcFractalUpZone() =>
    TF4_FractalUpZone = 0.0
    TF4_FractalUpZone := TF4_Up and TF4_Close[3] >= TF4_Open[3] ? TF4_Close[3] : TF4_Up and TF4_Close[3] < TF4_Open[3] ? TF4_Open[3] : TF4_FractalUpZone[1]
    TF4_FractalUpZone

TF4_FractalUpZone = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, TF4, TF4_CalcFractalUpZone())
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from the documentation: [Execution of Pine Script™ functions and historical context inside function blocks](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html?highlight=logging#execution-of-pine-script-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks)

In my case, `TF4_FractalUpZone[1]` is the previous value of `TF4_FractalUpZone` on the last call function call to `TF4_CalcFractalUpZone()`.